# How to set two declarations in awk Begin

Tags: awk

I want to have two declarations in my awk begin statement

This is my command so far

```
awk 'BEGIN {i=1, j=2} {print $i,$j}' <<< "col1 col2"
```

Which returns

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {i=1,j=2} {print $i,$j}
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
```

And I would like it to print

```
col1 col2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a semicolon:

```
awk 'BEGIN {i=1; j=2} {print $i,$j}' <<< "col1 col2"
```